# Drop linked server linked to itself

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I was trying to set up a linked server from within SSMS. I thought somewhere the wizard would ask for the server name and which database. It didn't (which means I obviously did something wrong) and it created a link to itself. How do I get rid of the linked server?

I haven't tried anything to fix it yet for fear I'll accidentally delete my real server. Can I just right click on the linked server and choose delete or am I hosed?

Comment: You can drop liked server from SSMS or use sp_dropserver. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-dropserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: For basic SQL Server link name of the link equals name of the target server.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to delete the linked server.